# How to find command line executable (cli) in TYPO3 in Composer and non Composer mode?

Tags: typo3, command-line-interface

The paths for the cli command has changed somewhere from TYPO3 7 to 8. Also, on my  TYPO3 system there are 2 files:

- ./public/typo3/sysext/core/bin/typo3
- ./vendor/typo3/cms-cli/typo3

Which is the correct executable to run cli commands in TYPO3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have installed your system with Composer, you can run `vendor/bin/typo3` (or `bin/typo3` depending on the setting of the [bin-dir](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/vendor-binaries.md#can-vendor-binaries-be-installed-somewhere-other-than-vendor-bin-) in your composer.json file or env variable) since TYPO3 8. This should be a symbolic link pointing to the correct executable.

When you run the command without parameters, it should output a list of the available commands, e.g.

```
vendor/bin/typo3
```

So, you can execute a command like this:

```
vendor/bin/typo3 referenceindex:update
```

---

**For TYPO3 8 and above:**

With Composer:

```
vendor/bin/typo3
# or
bin/typo3
```

Without Composer:

```
typo3/sysext/core/bin/typo3
```

The paths may vary slightly, depending on how you setup your system.

---

**TYPO3 7**

```
typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh
```

Comment: In composer mode, you can also find a symlink to the executable in vendor/bin/typo3.

Comment: I agree, this makes it simpler. Thanks! I will update my answer.

Comment: Thx Sybille for highlightning the differences between TYPO3 versions.
Backend module Scheduler also shows the current execution path under information, to run planned tasks via cli.